# Password is visible in online sign up form

Tags: password-management, account-security

I am about to sign up for an online school, which is an accredited statewide online school, and notice that the password they want me to enter is fully visible on the form. Should I be concern about their information security? Does a form like this indicates that the way the way the school protects students' data is not secure, such as storing password verbatim rather than something like one-way hash?

If such forms violate established data security practices, what document(s) should I refer to the school's IT people regarding that?

[image: Online sign-up form]

UPDATE:

The next screen reveals the password verbatim. I clipped away the user content, but the password was shown unencrypted, along with the student name and the user name:

[image: After sign-up]

Could you point me to the industry standards of password storage that I could forward them?

Comment: What does enrollment in this site get you? Will you be able to set up credit card payments? See your confidential transcript? Or is this just for ordering class photos?

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/100103

Comment: Please don't look up a web development standard and forward it to the school. That is not going to do a thing but get them to roll their eyes at you. Even if they are violating every security principle known to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't look up a web development standard and forward it to the school. That is not going to do a thing but get them to roll their eyes at you. Even if they are violating every security principle known to programming, "preaching at them" is not going to get results.

This is an enrollment form designed for parents to sign up multiple students. From a UI perspective, displaying the passwords so that the parent can record them is perfectly normal. You still have no idea how the passwords are stored on the server-side.

I'm not saying that everything is fine. I am saying that you don't have enough evidence to support a claim of improper password handling, and what you want to do with evidence, if you find it, is not going to work.

If you are wanting to know more, then use your status as a student to ask "curiosity questions":

> I'm very interested in web development. I was using your form and I
> saw that the site displayed the passwords in cleartext back to me. I
> was reading about password hashing in web applications and I was
> curious to know how you store student passwords and how you were able
> to display the passwords in plaintext. How did you do that?

You might get engagement, get actual technical details, and if it all comes back horrible, then you need to go to your state's department that handles personal data protection and report it.

Answer (score 3):

The main risks with making a password visible are:

- The password can be seen by someone shoulder-surfing
- The HTML element type may discern how the browser or browser extensions treat the data, possibly sending it to Google or another entity (e.g. for spell check).

There are some advantages to allowing the user to see what they entered, even temporarily. A user can check if they made any mistakes while typing it in. This is less effective when you already need to enter it twice though.

> Does a form like this indicates that the way the way the school protects students' data is not secure, such as storing password verbatim rather than something like one-way hash?

From a technical standpoint, this form tells you nothing definitive about how the system works. Sure, you can make assumptions about their practices based on this, but they will just be assumptions.

In general, while there are some downsides to this, I don't think it is a huge issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I am about to sign up for an online school, which is an accredited
> statewide online school, and notice that the password they want me to
> enter is fully visible on the form. Should I be concern about their
> information security?

Not necessarily. Masking the password simply protects it from the prying eyes of someone looking over your shoulder.

The more interesting question is: is the form submitted securely using **https** ?

The **password policy** is very outdated and not very smart: "At least 8 characters long and must only contains letters and numbers". Seriously ? In 2020 ? They effectively enforce poor/less than ideal passwords.

So many sites will insist on at least one **special character** nowadays (that still doesn't mean the password policy is sound though).

What this tells me: the designer is not very confident in the ability of the code to handle special characters. Red flag. Old code (legacy) perhaps. Or it is an arbitrary decision, not a technical constraint. Assumption: the developer has no clue. Red flag.

When you think of it, requesting **password confirmation** becomes pointless in this scenario, since you can see exactly what you typed. The same could be said about the E-mail too. What is the point of frustrating users with double input.

> Does a form like this indicates that the way the way the school
> protects students' data is not secure, such as storing password
> verbatim rather than something like one-way hash?

Not necessarily but you can't be sure. You can try the password reminder feature (if there is one) and see if it sends you the original password back. Then it's bad and you have proof that the password is stored in **plain text**. However, if you get a link to reset, that does not prove that the password is indeed stored in hashed form. Only a look at the code or the database could confirm this, but we can make educated guesses.

> If such forms violate established data security practices, what
> document(s) should I refer to the school's IT people regarding that?

First of all, try to evaluate the scope of the problem. Is https used ? Can you prove that passwords are stored in plain text ? If any of the boxes tick, you can add the poor password policy on top of it. While you are it, you can look at the URL, also after submitting the form and see if it carries bits of data that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Yes, it's https:

Comment: Just updated the question: after sign-up was completed the next form showed my password verbatim.

Comment: @Michael you still don't know how it was stored on their servers.

Comment: *"Then it's bad and you have proof that the password is stored in plain text"* Not necessarily, the password could be stored reversibly encrypted. This is sometimes necessary, for example if a website allows minors to register, and requires that parents be able to retrieve their child's password.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hint in the congrats page that suggests the account you created is a **shared account**, which means the students will use the same credentials to login to the online school. The people behind this choice must have a proper business justification. Only them can tell the motivation.

They are telling you :

> Your students can now start accessing the Online School. Simply using the user name  and password you created.

.. and remind you to keep a copy of "clear-text" password somewhere :

> Please take a moment. copy or print this page for future reference.

So you may probably share it with your students.